# Application Crash instead of giving Internet Connection Error

Tags: android

if my device is not connected to internet then it should give internet connection error in Toast. But my application crashes. It does not catch error of No Internet Connection. my code works perfectly on internet connection . Please help me

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String s=postData();
            return s;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
            pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        public String postData() {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header


            String origresponseText="";
            try {
                  DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/ServletParams/AndroidServlet");

                // Add your data  cnic,mobileNo,name,address,nextkin
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1",cnic));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", mobileNo));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param3", name));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param4", address));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param5", nextkin));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param6", sendImages));


                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
         /* execute */

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                  HttpEntity rp = response.getEntity();
origresponseText=readContent(response);

            } 
      catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
      catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "sorry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            String responseText = origresponseText.substring(7, origresponseText.length());
            return responseText;

        }


    }
    String readContent(HttpResponse response)
    {
        String text = "";
        InputStream in =null;

        try {
            in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line);
                }
                text = sb.toString();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "sorry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        finally {
            try {

              in.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }

return text;
    }
```

Here is a log:

```
10-17 19:45:05.061: E/AndroidRuntime(22597): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
10-17 19:45:05.061: E/AndroidRuntime(22597):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
10-17 19:45:05.061: E/AndroidRuntime(22597):    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:322)
10-17 19:45:05.061: E/AndroidRuntime(22597):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
10-17 19:45:05.061: E/AndroidRuntime(22597):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
10-17 19:45:05.061: E/AndroidRuntime(22597):    at com.example.androidufoneapp.CustomerRegistrationL0$MyAsyncTask.postData(CustomerRegistrationL0.java:647)
10-17 19:45:05.061: E/AndroidRuntime(22597):    at com.example.androidufoneapp.CustomerRegistrationL0$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(CustomerRegistrationL0.java:602)
10-17 19:45:05.061: E/AndroidRuntime(22597):    at com.example.androidufoneapp.CustomerRegistrationL0$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(CustomerRegistrationL0.java:1)
10-17 19:45:05.061: E/AndroidRuntime(22597):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-17 19:45:05.061: E/AndroidRuntime(22597):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-17 19:45:05.061: E/AndroidRuntime(22597):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: The error is not related to internet connection errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think , you have got Window Leak because when there is no internet connection your code is accessing the UI thread in doInBackground method. Take a look at your Toast Messages in your ReadContent method. Your Toast messages will access UI thread if there's no internet and it's got exception.But as your app is in Background thread at that time , so you'll get window leak error and app will crash because you can't access the App UI from background thread.

Ok..to fix this , Remove the Toast messages from the PostData method. If you want to show toast then show it in onPostExecute method. I suggest another good way.

Use this method to check if connection is available using the following method

```
public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Then when you start your AsyncTask , do like this

```
if(isOnline()){
   // Start your AsyncTask
} else{
  // Show internet not available alert
}
```

You'll need to add ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission as well to use this method. Hope it helps.

Comment: i have tried:   try{
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
             catch (Exception e){
              
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();.....it's not working

Comment: What you tried will not work , because your code will always enter the try block. So, window leak will still occur.

Comment: Ayon i used your strategy ..it's not working..i have tried if(isOnline){}

Comment: Please be specific , what's the error you are getting now? If I can see your logcat , may be I can help.

Comment: I have edited my answer , you should remove the Toast Messages from PostData method as you are using it from doInBackground.Remove the Toast message lines and you can print the exception message there if you wish in Exception block. The code should work ok. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're calling `Toast.makeText` inside a method that is called by `doInBackground`. This method is touching the UI thread, which is forbidden inside `doInBackground`, you should call `Toast.makeText` from `onPostExecute`, according to the result of your query.

You could do this :

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    if (!result.equals("")){ // Check to see if String result contains a result or in case or error, is still your empty String you assigned it
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // errorMessage can be a String that you keep track of inside your catch clauses or a generic error message
    }
}
```

You also need to remove all calls to `Toast.makeText` from the catch clauses inside your `readContent` method.

Additionally, it is a good idea to check for internet connection **before** you launch your AsyncTask, and only handle IO errors and the like inside the AsyncTask code. Ayon's solution will work for that.

Comment: i am not getting your point. Can you give e me a answer in code .thanks

Comment: Your method postData is calling Toast.makeText inside the catch blocks, which is what is causing the error. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your toasts inside main ui thread, like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // runs on UI thread
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Put both of then like this and your problem will be solved! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Before calling AsyncTask first check the connectivity.

Create a class called AppUtility.

```
public class AppUtility {
    /**
         * Determine connectivity. a utility method to determine Internet
         * connectivity this is invoked before every web request
         * 
         * @param ctx
         *            the context
         * @return true, if successful
         */
        public static boolean determineConnectivity(Context context) {
            ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return info != null && info.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED;
        } 

}
```

And check the connection like this

```
if (AppUtility.determineConnectivity(this))
  new MyAsyncTask().execute();
else
Toast.makeText(this, "sorry! No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Hope this will help you.